# Opensource project based on Symfony 2 or Zend Framework 2

Tags: git, zend-framework, open-source, symfony

I am looking for repositories with open project that are good examples for learning.

I will be grateful if somebody share any links here.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

For symfony2 checkout [lichess](https://github.com/ornicar/lichess).

Comment: Thanks for this project it's perfect for learning new stuff.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication

Use the google, luke ;)

Comment: I am using too, but you know maybe I miss something very good.

Comment: Good work then :) I personally know very little about zend and php in general, so hopefully someone more knowledgeable can help you out! I think there are chat channels on SO you might be able to find some good stuff there too.